# Determine flags used during 'configure' step of an installation after the fact

Tags: installation, ruby, configuration, flags

So in my case, I'm upgrading a Ruby install from a low patch level to a higher one.  I wanted know exactly what flags, if any, were used in the previous `./configure` step of the installation process.

Is there a way to determine this unilaterally?  At the very least, is there a way to determine this for Ruby?

Thanks,
-a

Comment: Probably do not have the "old" build directory anymore do you? You could peek in the config.cache file or w/e it's called. But I am guessing that is long gone.

Comment: Yeah, it's long gone, but good idea though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ruby you can look at `rbconfig.rb`, specifically `CONFIG["configure_args"]`. On my Fedora 16 box it is `/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb`.

Comment: Brilliant!  That's EXACTLY what I'm looking for.  On our machine it's at `/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb`.  Thanks man!!